# code::Blocks | SFML errors

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I'm trying to get SFML to work on code::blocks but I keep getting errors whenever I try to test a sample code. I followed the tutorial from http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-cb.php but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm not really good at this, so if someone could help it'd be awesome.

Here is a screenshot of the code and the errors: http://i39.tinypic.com/nbdysj.jpg

Here are the errors:

```
obj\Debug\test.o||In function `main':|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|5|undefined reference to `sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|5|undefined reference to `sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|5|undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|6|undefined reference to `sf::CircleShape::CircleShape(float, unsigned int)'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|5|undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|7|undefined reference to `sf::Color::Green'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|7|undefined reference to `sf::Shape::setFillColor(sf::Color const&)'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|15|undefined reference to `sf::Window::close()'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|12|undefined reference to `sf::Window::pollEvent(sf::Event&)'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|18|undefined reference to `sf::Color::Color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|18|undefined reference to `sf::RenderTarget::clear(sf::Color const&)'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|19|undefined reference to `sf::RenderStates::Default'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|19|undefined reference to `sf::RenderTarget::draw(sf::Drawable const&, sf::RenderStates const&)'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|20|undefined reference to `sf::Window::display()'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|9|undefined reference to `sf::Window::isOpen() const'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|23|undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\test\test.cpp|23|undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'|
obj\Debug\test.o||In function `~CircleShape':|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\SFML-2.0\include\SFML\Graphics\CircleShape.hpp|42|undefined reference to `vtable for sf::CircleShape'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\SFML-2.0\include\SFML\Graphics\CircleShape.hpp|42|undefined reference to `vtable for sf::CircleShape'|
C:\Users\Mads\Desktop\SFML-2.0\include\SFML\Graphics\CircleShape.hpp|42|undefined reference to `sf::Shape::~Shape()'|
||=== Build finished: 20 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Please put the code in the question. 1) It's easier to read 2) People might want to copy/paste it. But at a quick guess, it's a linking error. Something isn't set up to find the library containing all these symbols.

Comment: I would suggest you go back through the steps under `Creating and configuring a SFML project` and make sure you followed them all correctly, in particular the section that starts `The next step is to link your application to the SFML libraries (.a files) that your code will need.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.                                                 I'm gonna try redo everything and see if it works

Comment: it looks you have not set the library file in build options for the project in code::blocks .

Comment: I did set it though.                                                   Btw I just did it all over, and each time I do something in the program it gives me"Environment error": Can't find compiler executable in your configured search path's for GNU GCC Compiler

Comment: there are beautiful tutorials on sfml-dev.org on how to set up your IDE to work with sfml. Following the instructions step-by-step should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I had to do two steps to get it working.

1) Compiling SFML manually instead of using the packaged version.

2) Adding the manually compiled version to the project in the build options.

Before that I was constantly getting those errors even though I specified everything as described in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You should add to your CB project file *.cbp this:

```
<Linker>
       <Add library="GL" />
</Linker>
```